# why is so many instrumetationVerison folder under External libraries in project opentelemetry-java-instrumentation after gradle assemble

Tags: build, open-telemetry, assemble

as describled in the title above,i wanna know why is so many instrumetationVerison folder under External libraries in project opentelemetry-java-instrumentation after gradle assemble?[image]